# What is the general case of QuickCheck's promote function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, quickcheck, category-theory

What is the general term for a functor with a structure resembling QuickCheck's `promote` function, i.e., a function of the form:

```
promote :: (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)
```

(this is the inverse of `flip $ fmap (flip ($)) :: f (a -> b) -> (a -> f b)`).  Are there even any functors with such an operation, other than `(->) r` and `Id`?  (I'm sure there must be).  Googling 'quickcheck promote' only turned up the QuickCheck documentation, which doesn't give `promote` in any more general context AFAICS; searching SO for 'quickcheck promote' produces no results.

Comment: Is [`sequenceA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) relevant?

Comment: Let me see.  Substituting into the type of `sequenceA`, we would get `t = (->) a` and `f = f`.  So if `(->) a` had a `Traversable` instance, this function would exist for all `a`.  I think `Traversable ((->) a)` requires `(Bounded a, Enum a)` of or the equivalent, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, the [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package family provides the [requisite `Traversable` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-reverse-instances-1.0/docs/src/Data-Universe-Instances-Traversable.html).

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, ah, given `Finite`, which I guess is essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I found these ways of constructing an `f` with the `promote` morphism:

- `f = Identity`
- if f and g both have `promote` then the pair functor `h t = (f t, g t)` also does
- if f and g both have `promote` then the composition `h t = f (g t)` also does
- if f has the `promote` property and g is any contrafunctor then the functor `h t = g t -> f t` has the `promote` property

The last property can be generalized to profunctors g, but then f will be merely a profunctor, so it's probably not very useful, unless you only require profunctors.

Now, using these four constructions, we can find many examples of functors `f` for which `promote` exists:

```
f t = (t,t)

f t = (t, b -> t)

f t = (t -> a) -> t

f t = ((t,t) -> b) -> (t,t,t)

f t = ((t, t, c -> t, (t -> b) -> t) -> a) -> t
```

Also note that the `promote` property implies that `f` is pointed.

```
point :: t -> f t
point x = fmap (const x) (promote id)
```

Essentially the same question: [Is this property of a functor stronger than a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649497/is-this-property-of-a-functor-stronger-than-a-monad)

Comment: Could you add the actual instances you're suggesting? For example what does this instance for `(t, t)` look like? When implementing `a -> (b, b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)`, does it just apply the input function to both `a`s and throw away 2/4 `b`s?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin The instance for `(t, t)` requires us to implement `promote:: (a -> (b, b)) -> (a -> b, a -> b)`, not `a -> (b, b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)`.  Implementing `promote:: (a -> (b, b)) -> (a -> b, a -> b)` does not throw away anything; `promote f = (fst . f, snd . f)`. Try to derive the general construction: if `f` and `g` have promote then `h` has promote where `h a = (f a, g a)`. There is only one way to implement `promote` for `h`, and it does not throw away any information.

Answer (score 5):

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

Given that Monad is more powerful an interface than Applicative, this tell us that `a -> f b` can do more things than `f (a -> b)`. This tells us that a function of type `(a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)` can't be injective. The domain is bigger than the codomain, in a handwavey manner. This means there's no way you can possibly preserve behavior of the function. It just doesn't work out across generic functors.

You can, of course, characterize functors in which that operation is injective. `Identity` and `(->) a` are certainly examples. I'm willing to bet there are more examples, but nothing jumps out at me immediately.

Answer (score 1):

[Data.Distributive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html) has

```
class Functor g => Distributive g where
  distribute :: Functor f => f (g a) -> g (f a)
  -- other non-critical methods
```

Renaming your variables, you get

```
promote :: (c -> g a) -> g (c -> a)
```

Using slightly invalid syntax for clarity,

```
promote :: ((c ->) (g a)) -> g ((c ->) a)
```

`(c ->)` is a `Functor`, so the type of `promote` is a special case of the type of `distribute`. Thus every `Distributive` functor supports your `promote`. I don't know if any support `promote` but not `Distributive`.

Comment: `Distributive` is strictly stronger than `promote`. Every `Distributive` functor `g` is representable: that is, there exists a constant type `b` such that `g t = b -> t `. However, functors such as `g t = (t -> a) -> t` have `promote` but are not representable and thus fail to be `Distributive`.

More generally, a functor `g` defined as `g t = c t -> h t` has `promote` if  `c` is any contrafunctor and `h` has `promote. This construction can define a `Distributable` only if `c` is a constant (contra)functor.