# Haskell (a -> m a) -> m (a -> a) -> m (a -> a)

Tags: haskell, monads

I've been digging into Haskell for the past months, I've run into a situation with monads that I am not quite sure how to handle.

I have one value of type `a -> m a` and a second of type `m (a -> a)` and I need to compose them such that the result of the first ends up as the input into the of the second and produces a `m (a -> a)` if possible. I've been stuck on this for the past day now and I'm not wrapping my head around it. I suppose that I am looking for a function like `(a -> m a) -> m (a -> a) -> m (a -> a)`. I can provide a more concrete example if it makes more sense.

Comment: You can *sort of* do what you ask if you're willing to perform the monadic actions associated with all possible input `a` values at once up front. Occasionally this is what you want -- but usually not.

Comment: You need to add some laws to this type signature. Otherwise, an implementation could ignore the first argument and return the second without change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do this, in general.  The problem is your result type: `m (a -> a)`.  This is a *single* monadic action which produces a function; but your first input has the form `a -> m a`, which (potentially) produces a *different* monadic action for each argument.  So, for example, for the `[]` monad `[a -> a]` is list of functions with a fixed length, whereas `a -> [a]` can have a different length for each argument.  So there's no way to 'push' the function type back into the `m` in general; see [What is the general case of QuickCheck's promote function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264411/what-is-the-general-case-of-quickchecks-promote-function) for a related SO question.

If `a -> m a` would work for what you need, then you can turn your `m (a -> a)` argument into `a -> m a` using

```
\ x -> fmap ($ x) af
```

and use `>=>` (or `<=<`, it's not clear from your types) to compose the functions together.

Comment: Yep! The asked-for function would downgrade a Monad action to an Applicative action, which is impossible. What they should do instead is upgrade the Applicative action to a Monad action.

Comment: That's generally what I figured I was going to need to do. Just didn't have the words to reason about it yet.