# Is this property of a functor stronger than a monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, functor, category-theory

While thinking about how to generalize monads, I came up with the following property of a functor F:

```
inject :: (a -> F b) -> F(a -> b)
```

-- which should be a natural transformation in both a and b.

In absence of a better name, I call the functor F **bindable** if there exists a natural transformation `inject` shown above.

The main question is, whether this property is already known and has a name, and how is it related to other well-known properties of functors (such as, being applicative, monadic, pointed, traversable, etc.)

The motivation for the name "bindable" comes from the following consideration: Suppose M is a monad and F is a "bindable" functor. Then one has the following natural morphism:

```
fbind :: M a -> (a -> F(M b)) -> F(M b)
```

This is similar to the monadic "bind",

```
bind :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
```

except the result is decorated with the functor F.

The idea behind `fbind` was that a generalized monadic operation can produce not just a single result M b but a "functor-ful" F of such results. I want to express the situation when a monadic operation yields several "strands of computation" rather than just one; each "strand of computation" being again a monadic computation.

Note that every functor F has the morphism

```
eject :: F(a -> b) -> a -> F b
```

which is converse to "inject". But not every functor F has "inject".

Examples of functors that have "inject": `F t = (t,t,t)`  or `F t = c -> (t,t)` where c is a constant type. Functors `F t = c` (constant functor) or `F t = (c,t)` are not "bindable" (i.e. do not have "inject"). The continuation functor `F t = (t -> r) -> r` also does not seem to have `inject`.

The existence of "inject" can be formulated in a different way. Consider the "reader" functor `R t = c -> t` where c is a constant type. (This functor is applicative and monadic, but that's beside the point.) The "inject" property then means `R (F t) -> F (R t)`, in other words, that R commutes with F. Note that this is not the same as the requirement that F be traversable; that would have been `F (R t) -> R (F t)`, which is always satisfied for any functor F with respect to R.

So far, I was able to show that "inject" implies "fbind" for any monad M.

In addition, I showed that every functor F that has "inject" will also have these additional properties:

- it is pointed

`point ::  t -> F t`

- if F is "bindable" and applicative then F is also a monad
- if F and G are "bindable" then so is the pair functor F * G  (but not F + G)
- if F is "bindable" and A is any profunctor then the (pro)functor `G t = A t -> F t` is bindable
- the identity functor is bindable.

Open questions:

- is the property of being "bindable" equivalent to some other well-known properties, or is it a new property of a functor that is not usually considered?
- are there any other properties of the functor "F" that follow from the existence of "inject"?
- do we need any laws for "inject", would that be useful? For instance, we could require that R (F t) be isomorphic to F (R t) in one or both directions.

Comment: Side question: Do you have some useful piece of code which demonstrates the usefulness of this?

Comment: @BitTickler Not yet. Before writing any code, I want to understand the the properties of the functors I'm going to use. It's much easier and faster to work with types than with actual code.

Comment: How did you show that every bindable functor is pointed?

Comment: I think you've invented `Traversable`, but can't check right now

Comment: @jberryman: it's certainly not _equivalent_ to `Traversable` (e.g. you can easily traverse `Const`), but it does seem related.

Comment: @jberryman I think it's actually the "opposite" of `Traversable` in some sense. `sequenceA` would be able to yank `->` to the _outside_ of a `Traversable` (using `(->) r`'s `Applicative` instance) but not the other way round. IOW `sequenceA :: Traversable t => t (a -> b) -> a -> t b`

Comment: @Bergi To show that `inject` implies `point`, first we set a = F t in `inject` and get `inject :: (F t -> F t) -> F(F t -> t)`. We then apply this to the identity morphism `id :: F t -> F t`. We obtain a (naturally defined) value of `F(F t -> t)`. Now, we apply the "strength" of the functor: `x -> F y -> F (x,y)` and project this to obtain the morhpism `x -> F y -> F x`. Now we set x = t and y = F t -> t in this morphism. We obtain `t -> F(F t -> t) -> F t`. Since we already have a natural value of `F (F t -> t)`, we thus obtain a natural transformation `t -> F t`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I think the property `F (a->b) -> a -> F b` holds for any functor F, not only for traversable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765324/haskell-function-from-a-b-a-b

Comment: @winitzki Ah, so basically `point x = fmap (const x) (inject id)`?

Comment: @Bergi Right. This question has been closed as duplicate, but the other question does not really have a satisfactory answer as to what properties characterize F such that `inject` exists.

Comment: @winitzki Ah, yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @winitzki: agreed, I reverted the closing for this reason. I _reckon_ that this property is much stronger than `Monad` and in fact any such functor `F` is equivalent to the function functor `(Log F ->)`, where `Log` basically counts the number of times that `t` appears in `F t`, which must be fixed and >0. But I don't have a proof for this, and in fact I doubt that `Log` would be actually computable, at least not in Haskell types. It might be possible mathematically, but I wouldn't be surprised if it required the axiom of choice or something.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you! Let's hope someone has a better answer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I guess what you are saying is that F must be representable with a constant type: that is, there must be a constant type b such that F t is isomorphic to b -> t. But, so far, I have some examples of a "bindable" F that are not of this form. Namely, if A is a profunctor then A t -> t is bindable. An example is the "writer" contrafunctor A t = (t -> r). Then F t = (t -> r) -> t  is bindable but not of the form b -> t for a constant b.

Comment: This looks way stronger than a monad to me. From a purely practical point of view, there's no way we can construct something like `inject id :: IO (IO a -> a)`. That would be very dangerous, effectively providing access to `unsafePerformIO` in pure code with the mild requirement that eventually this is being called from IO (which always happens, since we start from `main`). Basically we only have to do `main = do upIO <- inject id ; print (pureF upIO 12) ; ...` to allow the purely typed `pureF` to run side-effects. Scary.

Comment: Note that I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264411/what-is-the-general-case-of-quickchecks-promote-function a while ago, and as far as anyone could find, the only functors with this property are `Identity` and `(->) a`.  So I suspect it's *much* stronger than `Monad`.

Comment: @jcast Thank you for linking to your older question. So it's called `promote` and not `inject`. I found a wider class of examples within exponential-polynomial functors, as I detailed in my question. You can construct these functors from Identity, by taking pairs, and by mapping from a contrafunctor.

Comment: @winitzki Oh, can you? Your question was hard for me to read :).  Would you mind summarizing your construction as an answer on my question, so I can switch my accepted answer?

Comment: How about `F = Maybe`, `inject _ = Nothing`, or any other functor `F` with `F Void` nonempty? Surely you want some kind of condition on `inject`.

Comment: @ReidBarton Indeed, I want a condition that would prohibit trivial `inject` instances for nontrivial functors. Perhaps `eject . inject = id` or vice versa, where `eject :: F (a->b) -> a -> F b`.

Comment: [`Distributive f`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html#t:Distributive) gets you `distribute :: Functor g => g (f a) -> f (g a)`, which from a Haskell type standpoint is more powerful than your function. I don't know if it satisfies your category-theoretic laws. Every `Representable` functor is distributive, and the documentation says the other way round holds mathematically.

Comment: If I calculated correctly, for your `F t = (t -> r) -> t` example, `eject . inject` is the identity but `inject . eject` isn't the identity.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you! This link is very useful, I will read that documentation.

Comment: @ReidBarton Interesting! I will try to check your calculations.

Comment: @ReidBarton I checked and got the same result. For "bindable" polynomial functors F, both `eject . inject` and `inject . eject` are identity. The non-identity appears only as `inject . eject` and only for "bindable" functors F of the form F t = A t -> G t where A is a contrafunctor and G is bindable. The reason is that the chain of morphisms `A (a->t) -> A t -> A (a->t)` does not yield identity, while `A t -> A (a->t) -> A t` does.

Comment: @dfeuer I think you should make that an answer

Comment: I'd like to ruminate on this a bit more, and at the same time wait for other people to say something. Then, if no one wants to, perhaps I would write an answer, summarizing what everyone said here: 0) improved definition of "bindable" with the law `eject . inject = id` 1) "bindable" is strictly stronger than monad, and strictly weaker than "distributive". 2) specific examples of bindable and non-bindable functors, as well as bindable that is not distributive.

Comment: @leftroundabout: Isn't `Log f = forall a. f a -> a`?

Comment: @TomEllis This `Log` will not always work as a "logarithm". It's a weird type function that does not have any of the properties of the usual logarithm except for a single example: if `f a = r -> a` then `Log f = r`. Ordinary logarithm has properties such as `log(a*b) = log(a)+log(b)`, which this `Log` does not have.

Comment: @winitzki Firstly, I'm not claiming it has any properties besides the one @leftroundabout speculated about: `Log F ->` is isomorphic to `F` (for the class of `F` under consideration).  Secondly, it's not clear to me that it *doesn't* have the property you claim (where we use `Product f g a = Product (f a) (g a)` and `Sum f g a = Sum (Either (f a) (g a))`, of course).

Comment: @TomEllis Many examples of using `Log` show properties very different from what you would expect. 1) We have `Log (Sum F G) = Product (Log F) (Log G)` instead of `log(a*b) = log(a)+log(b)`. 2) Defining a functor `g` as `type g a = (Int, a, a)`, what would you expect `Log g` to be? Calculations show `Log g = Int -> Bool`. 3) What would you expect `Log Maybe` to be? Calculations show that `Log Maybe` is a recursive type equivalent to natural numbers, `data Nat = One | Succ Nat`. I'd say all of these examples show quite unexpected results, showing that `Log` is not at all similar to a logarithm.

Comment: Correction: Calculations show that `Log Maybe` is void.  I mixed it up with `Log h` where `h` is defined by `type h a = (Maybe a) -> a`. For that type constructor, `Log h` is equivalent to the natural numbers type `Nat` defined by `data Nat = One | Succ Nat`.

Comment: @winitzki It's interesting.  It does seem to have some bizarre properties.  It would be nice to see them written down somewhere bigger than a tiny text box.

Comment: @TomEllis All of that, and much more, will hopefully be in the book I'm writing now. https://github.com/winitzki/sofp

Comment: Apologies if this has already been answered somewhere, but what exactly is the instance for `(a -> (b, b)) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)`? Does it throw away some data? Maybe all the instances are obvious to the folks in the discussion, but it would be helpful for the slowpokes among us if you could just explicitly write out the instances you're suggesting in your question/answer @winitzki.

Comment: Assuming `Whatever f => (f a, f a)` is *not* an instance I probably know what this is, but it's hard to say without knowing what the actual instance should look like.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To improve terminology a little bit, I propose to call these functors "rigid" instead of "bindable". The motivation for saying "rigid" will be explained below.

### Definition

A functor `f` is called **rigid** if it has the `inject` method as shown. Note that every functor has the `eject` method.

```
class (Functor f) => Rigid f where
  inject :: (a -> f b) -> f(a -> b)

  eject :: f(a -> b) -> a -> f b
  eject fab x = fmap (\ab -> ab x) fab
```

The law of "nondegeneracy" must hold:

```
eject . inject = id
```

### Properties

A rigid functor is always pointed:

```
instance (Rigid f) => Pointed f where
  point :: t -> f t
  point x = fmap (const x) (inject id)
```

If a rigid functor is applicative then it is automatically monadic:

```
instance (Rigid f, Applicative f) => Monad f where
  bind :: f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b
  bind fa afb = (inject afb) <*> fa
```

The property of being rigid is not comparable (neither weaker nor stronger) than the property of being monadic: If a functor is rigid, it does not seem to follow that it is automatically monadic (although I don't know specific counterexamples for this case). If a functor is monadic, it does not follow that it is rigid (there are counterexamples).

Basic counterexamples of monadic functors that are not rigid are `Maybe` and `List`. These are functors that have more than one constructor: such functors cannot be rigid.

The problem with implementing `inject` for `Maybe` is that `inject` must transform a function of type `a -> Maybe b` into `Maybe(a -> b)` while `Maybe` has two constructors. A function of type `a -> Maybe b` could return different constructors for different values of `a`. However, we are supposed to construct a value of type `Maybe(a -> b)`. If for some `a` the given function produces `Nothing`, we don't have a `b` so we can't produce a total function `a->b`. Thus we cannot return `Just(a->b)`; we are forced to return `Nothing` as long as the given function produces `Nothing` even for one value of `a`. But we cannot check that a given function of type `a -> Maybe b` produces `Just(...)` for all values of `a`. Therefore we are forced to return `Nothing` in all cases. This will not satisfy the law of nondegeneracy.

So, we can implement `inject` if `f t` is a container of "fixed shape" (having only one constructor). Hence the name "rigid".

Another explanation as to why rigidity is more restrictive than monadicity is to consider the naturally defined expression

```
(inject id) :: f(f a -> a)
```

where `id :: f a -> f a`. This shows that we can have an f-algebra `f a -> a` for any type `a`, as long as it is wrapped inside `f`. It is not true that any monad has an algebra; for example, the various "future" monads as well as the `IO` monad describe computations of type `f a` that do not allow us to extract values of type `a` - we shouldn't be able to have a method of type `f a -> a` even if wrapped inside an `f`-container. This shows that the "future" monads and the `IO` monad are not rigid.

A property that is *strictly stronger* than rigidity is [distributivity](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html#t:Distributive) from one of E. Kmett's packages. A functor `f` is distributive if we can interchange the order as in `p (f t) -> f (p t)` for *any* functor `p`. Rigidity is the same as being able to interchange the order only with respect to the "reader" functor `r t = a -> t`. So, all distributive functors are rigid.

All distributive functors are necessarily representable, which means they are equivalent to the "reader" functor `c -> t` with some fixed type `c`. However, not all rigid functors are representable. An example is the functor `g` defined by

```
type g t = (t -> r) -> t
```

The functor `g` are not equivalent to `c -> t` with a fixed type `c`.

### Constructions and examples

Further examples of rigid functors that are not representable (i.e. not "distributive") are functors of the form `a t -> f t` where `a` is *any* contrafunctor and `f` is a rigid functor. Also, the Cartesian product and the composition of two rigid functors is again rigid. In this way, we can produce many examples of rigid functors within the exponential-polynomial class of functors.

My answer to [What is the general case of QuickCheck's promote function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264411/what-is-the-general-case-of-quickchecks-promote-function) also lists the constructions of rigid functors:

1. `f = Identity`
2. if `f` and `g` are both rigid then the functor product `h t = (f t, g t)` is also rigid
3. if `f` and `g` are both rigid then the composition `h t = f (g t)` is also rigid
4. if `f` is rigid and `g` is any contravariant functor then the functor `h t = g t -> f t` is rigid

One other property of rigid functors is that the type `r ()` is equivalent to `()`, i.e. there is only one distinct value of the type `r ()`. This value is `point ()`, where `point` is defined above for any rigid functor `r`. (I have a proof but I will not write it here, because I could not find an easy one-line proof.) A consequence is that a rigid functor must have only one constructor. This immediately shows that `Maybe`, `Either`, `List` etc. cannot be rigid.

### Connection with monads

If `f` is a monad that has a monad transformer of the "composed-outside" kind, `t m a = f (m a)`, then `f` is a rigid functor.

The "rigid monads" are possibly a subset of rigid functors because construction 4 only yields a rigid monad if `f` is also a rigid monad rather than an arbitrary rigid functor (but the contravariant functor `g` can still be arbitrary). However, I do not have any examples of a rigid functor that is not also a monad.

The simplest example of a rigid monad is `type r a = (a -> p) -> a`, the "search monad". (Here `p` is a fixed type.)

To prove that a monad `f` with the "composed-outside" transformer `t m a = f (m a)` also has an `inject` method, we consider the transformer `t m a` with the foreign monad `m` chosen as the reader monad, `m a = r -> a`. Then the function `inject` with the correct type signature is defined as

```
 inject = join @t . return @r . (fmap @m (fmap @f return @m))
```

with appropriate choices of type parameters.

The non-degeneracy law follows from the monadic naturality of `t`: the monadic morphism `m -> Identity` (substituting a value of type `r` into the reader) is lifted to the monadic morphism `t m a -> t Id a`. I omit the details of this proof.

### Use cases

Finally, I found two use cases for rigid functors.

The first use case was the original motivation for considering rigid functors: we would like to return several monadic results at once. If `m` is a monad and we want to have `fbind` as shown in the question, we need `f` to be rigid. Then we can implement `fbind` as

```
fbind :: m a -> (a -> f (m b)) -> f (m b)
fbind ma afmb = fmap (bind ma) (inject afmb)
```

We can use `fbind` to have monadic operations that return more than one monadic result (or, more generally, a rigid functor-ful of monadic results), for any monad `m`.

The second use case grows out of the following consideration. Suppose we have a program `p :: a` that internally uses a function `f :: b -> c`. Now, we notice that the function `f` is very slow, and we would like to refactor the program by replacing `f` with a monadic "future" or "task", or generally with a Kleisli arrow `f' :: b -> m c` for some monad `m`. We, of course, expect that the program `p` will become monadic as well: `p' :: m a`. Our task is to refactor `p` into `p'`.

The refactoring proceeds in two steps: First, we refactor the program `p` so that the function `f` is explicitly an argument of `p`. Assume that this has been done, so that now we have `p = q f` where

```
q :: (b -> c) -> a
```

Second, we replace `f` by `f'`. We now assume that `q` and `f'` are given. We would like to construct the new program `q'` of the type

```
q' :: (b -> m c) -> m a
```

so that `p' = q' f'`. The question is whether we can define a general combinator that will refactor `q` into `q'`,

```
refactor :: ((b -> c) -> a) -> (b -> m c) -> m a
```

It turns out that `refactor` can be constructed only if `m` is a rigid functor. In trying to implement `refactor`, we find essentially the same problem as when we tried to implement `inject` for `Maybe`: we are given a function `f' :: b -> m c` that could return different monadic effects `m c` for different `b`, but we are required to construct `m a`, which must represent the same monadic effect for all `b`. This cannot work, for instance, if `m` is a monad with more than one constructor.

If `m` is rigid (and we do not need to require that `m` be a monad), we can implement `refactor`:

```
refactor bca bmc = fmap bca (inject bmc)
```

If `m` is not rigid, we cannot refactor arbitrary programs. So far we have seen that the continuation monad is rigid, but the "future"-like monads and the `IO` monad are not rigid. This again shows that rigidity is, in a sense, a stronger property than monadicity.

Comment: The functor `W r` defined as `type W r t = (t->r) -> t` is actually a monad. The definition of `join` is 
`join :: W r (W r t) -> W r t;`
`join ww = \y -> ww (\w -> y (w y)) y)` and
I checked that all monad laws hold.
More generally, if `M` is a monad then the functor `g t = (M t -> r) -> M t` is also a monad, as are the functors `r -> M t` and `M(r -> t)`.

Comment: Is the continuation monad rigid?

Comment: @PyRulez No, the continuation monad is not rigid, despite what I said in the answer above. The required type for `inject` is not inhabitable for the continuation monad. In my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264411/what-is-the-general-case-of-quickchecks-promote-function  I have detailed some constructions of rigid functors, and the continuation monad does not fit there.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one possible presentation of rigid functors. I have taken the liberty to bikeshed your names a bit, for reasons I'll soon get to:

```
flap :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
flap u a = ($ a) <$> u 

class Functor g => Rigid g where
    fflip :: (a -> g b) -> g (a -> b)
    fflip f = (. f) <$> extractors

    extractors :: g (g a -> a)
    extractors = fflip id

-- "Left inverse"/non-degeneracy law: flap . fflip = id

instance Rigid ((->) r) where
    fflip = flip
```

Some remarks on my phrasing:

- I have changed the names of `inject` and `eject` to `fflip` and `flap`, mainly because, to my eyes, `flap` looks more like injecting, due to things like this:

  ```
  sweep :: Functor f => f a -> b -> f (a, b)
  sweep u b = flap ((,) <$> u) b
  ```
- I took the `flap` name [from *relude*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.5.0/docs/Relude-Functor-Fmap.html#v:flap). It is a play on `flip`, which is fitting because it is one of two symmetrical ways of generalising it. (We can either pull the function outside of an arbitrary `Functor`, as in `flap`, or pull a `Rigid` functor outside of a function, as in `fflip`.)
- `extractors` and `fflip` are interdefinable, making it possible to write, for example, this neat instance for the search/selection monad:

  ```
  newtype Sel r a = Sel { runSel :: (a -> r) -> a }
      deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad) via SelectT r Identity

  instance Rigid (Sel r) where
      -- Sel r (Sel r a -> a) ~ ((Sel r a -> a) -> r) -> Sel r a -> a
      extractors = Sel $ \k m -> m `runSel` \a -> k (const a)
  ```

A significant fact about `extractors` is that it gives rise to the following combinator:

```
distributeLike :: (Rigid g, Functor f) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
distributeLike m = (<$> m) <$> extractors
```

`distributeLike` is a more general version of `distribute` from [the `Distributive` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html). A lawful `distribute`, in turn, must abide by the following laws, which are dual to the laws of `Traversable`:

```
-- Identity law
fmap runIdentity . distribute = runIdentity

-- Composition law
fmap getCompose . distribute = distribute . fmap distribute . getCompose

-- Naturality law (always holds, by parametricity)
-- For any natural transformation t
fmap t . distribute = distribute . t
```

Since `fflip` is `distributeLike` with reader (that is, the function functor) as the other functor, and that `flap` is `distribute` for reader, both `flap . fflip = id` and `fflip . flap = id` are special cases of...

```
-- m :: f (g a)
distributeLike (distributeLike m) = m
```

... with appropriate choices of `f` and `g`. Now, the property above can be shown to be equivalent to the following conditions:

1. `distributeLike` for `g` follows the identity law of distributive functors (which, by the way, is equivalent to the rigid law);
2. `distributeLike` for `f` also follows the identity law of distributive functors;
3. Either of the following equivalent conditions hold:

   a. `distributeLike` for `f` follows the composition law of distributive functors; or

   b. All `f a -> a` functions made available by `extractors` for `f` are natural in `a`.

In particular, as `flap` is a lawful `distribute`, `flap . fflip = id` amounts to the identity law for `g` (condition #2), and `fflip . flap = id`, to `f` being distributive (conditions #1 and #3).

(The conditions above can be established by analysing `distributeLike . distributeLike = id` in terms of `extractors`, following a similar strategy to the one I applied to the composition law in [the "The roadblock, and a detour"](https://duplode.github.io/posts/every-distributive-is-representable.html#the-roadblock-and-a-detour) section of my post "Every Distributive is Representable".)

For the sake of illustration, let's consider the case of `Sel r`. As you note, it is rigid but not distributive, its `distributeLike` follows the identity law but not the composition one. Accordingly, `fflip . flap = id` does not hold.

With respect to finding a place for `Rigid` in the type class constellation, I would highlight condition #3b as being particularly interesting. It appears that, given how `extractors @f :: forall a. f (f a -> a)` is fully polymorphic in `a`, for it to provide non-natural `f a -> a` extractors `f` must not be strictly positive, corresponding to construction #4 in the "Constructions and examples" section of [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736535/2751851). The lack of strict positivity makes it possible for `extractors` to incorporate non-naturality (through a user-supplied contravariant argument) without having it specified explicitly in its definition. That being so, only functors that aren't strictly positive, such as `Sel r`, might be rigid without being distributive.

### Miscellaneous remarks

- Looking at `fflip` and `flap` from a monadic point of view, we might say that rigid monads are equipped with an injective conversion from Kleisli arrows to [static arrows](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.2/docs/Data-Semigroupoid-Static.html). With distributive monads, the conversion is upgraded to an isomorphism, which is a generalisation of how [`Applicative` and `Monad` are equivalent for `Reader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136614/2751851). One curious aspect of non-distributive rigid monads is that `fflip` being injective but not surjective implies that there are more static arrows than Kleisli arrows, which is a quite unusual state of affairs.
- `extractors` condenses much of what `Distributive` is about. For any distributive functor `g`, there is a `g (g a -> a)` value in which each position is filled with a matching `g a -> a` natural extractor function. With rigid functors that aren't distributive, this tidy correspondence no longer holds. With `Sel r`, for instance, every `a -> r` gives rise to an extractor, which generally isn't natural. That ultimately precludes having `distribute`/`fflip` (and also, by the way, [`tabulate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html)) as isomorphisms. In fact, the very notion of a shape with well-defined positions arguably breaks down when dealing with functors that aren't strictly positive.
- `Distributive` is dual to `Traversable`, and there are several correspondences between facts about the two classes. (In particular, the presentation of `Distributive` as `Representable`, in terms of an isomorphism to the reader functor, mirrors [the shape-and-contents formulation of `Traversable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199603/2751851), which can be expressed in terms of an isomorphism to some list-like functor.) That being so, one might wonder if a notion analogous to `Rigid` make sense for `Traversable`. I believe it does, though it is unclear how useful such a concept could possibly be. One example of a "co-rigid" pseudo-traversable would be a data structure equipped with a traversal that duplicates effects, but then discards the corresponding duplicate elements upon rebuilding the structure under the applicative layer, so that the identity law is followed, but not the composition one.

Comment: It is very interesting to see that `Rigid` has one fewer law than `Distributive`. Two questions: 1) Is `Traversable` similar in that it has two laws, and we can omit one law to have a weaker typeclass (your conjectured "co-Rigid")? 2)  What exactly is the usefulness of `Distributive` functors, and are there any examples of `Distributive` other than the `Reader` monad?

Comment: [1/3] (1) Indeed. Implementation details aside, the `Traversable` isomorphism amounts to a `clear` function, which empties the traversable structure giving out its shape and a list of its contents, and a `fill` function, which remakes the structure from shape and contents. `fill . clear = id` is equivalent to the identity law of `Traversable`, and adding `clear . fill = id` amounts to adding the composition law. A pseudo-traversable class with only the identity law is conceivable, but I suspect it wouldn't see much use -- the main problem being that traversals wouldn't compose cleanly.

Comment: [2/3] (2a) All distributive functors are isomorphic to `Reader r` for some `r`, though working with the non-function form can be more convenient depending on what one wants to do. Examples include infinite streams, fixed length vectors, and more generally any data structure with a fixed shape.

Comment: [3/3] (2b) While there are some nifty things one might do with the `Distributive` methods (for instance, with a vector type like `Duo a = Duo a a`, `cotraverse @Duo @[]` can be used to zip a list of vectors with a fold), the class has a rather tiny interface. The real power comes with `Representable`, which gives direct access to the isomorphism, thus making it possible to do with the functorial values almost anything you'd do with a function. (`Distributive` and `Representable` are separate classes mostly for the sake of packaging a simpler subset of the interface separately.)

Comment: @winitzki Beyond `Distributive` and `Representable`, there is still a further layer of bells and whistles that can be added to the interface, resulting in `Adjunction`, the class of Hask/Hask adjunctions. [The answer I wrote about it the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56704938/2751851) is somewhat relevant when it comes to what `Distributive`-like things can do.

Comment: What about a traversable that has `clear . fill = id` but not `fill . clear = id`? Would that be useful?

Comment: [1/2] @winitzki I believe a pseudo-traversable with only the composition law would be able to violate identity through rearrangements, as long as the rearrangements were idempotent. A traversal that only visits a certain number of elements from the structure might be a reasonable example.

Comment: [2/2] @winitzki Also, I am beginning to suspect that [`Witherable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.3.1/docs/Data-Witherable.html#t:Witherable) might have something to do with that idea (even though it is not exactly the same situation, as the rearrangements there are element-dependent): filtering is idempotent, and the witherable laws include a weakened identity and an unchanged composition law. So yes, it sounds like this other notion might be more fruitful.

Comment: @winitzki Revisiting this, I noticed a flaw in my reasoning: there is no reasonable `revert` for `Sel r` with the proper higher-rank type `((forall x. Sel r x -> x) -> a) -> Sel r a`. The `extractors` and `fflip` we wrote arise from an imitation of `revert` with type `((Sel r a -> a) -> a) -> Sel r a`. Given this less polymorphic type and `Sel r a` not being strictly positive, we can cheat and use a monomorphic-in-`a` `k :: a -> r` function to extract a result. That means most of my considerations about `revert`/`evert` don't apply to `Sel r`. I'll look into a way to fix this answer...

Comment: @winitzki I have rewritten the answer, removing the various tangents about `revert`/`evert`, and focusing on what looks like a nice, positive result: it appears that only functors that aren't strictly positive (i.e. your construction #4) can be rigid without being distributive.. By the way, considering the (counter-)example of `Sel` was vital towards making my understanding of `Distributive` clearer; thanks for getting me to think about it!

Answer (score 1):

We are all familiar with the `Traversable` typeclass, which can be boiled down to the following:

```hs
class Functor t => Traversable t
  where
  sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

This makes use of the concept of an `Applicative` functor. There is a laws-only [strengthening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596097/are-all-fixed-size-containers-strong-monoidal-functors-and-or-vice-versa) of the categorical concept underlying `Applicative` that goes like this:

```hs
-- Laxities of a lax monoidal endofunctor on Hask under (,)
zip :: Applicative f => (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
zip = uncurry $ liftA2 (,)

husk :: Applicative f => () -> f ()
husk = pure

-- Oplaxities of an oplax monoidal endofunctor on ... (this is trivial for all endofunctors on Hask)
unzip :: Functor f => f (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
unzip fab = (fst <$> fab, snd <$> fab)

unhusk :: f () -> ()
unhusk = const ()

-- The class
class Applicative f => StrongApplicative f

-- The laws
-- zip . unzip = id
-- unzip . zip = id
-- husk . unhusk = id
-- unhusk . husk = id -- this one is trivial
```

The linked question and its answers have more details, but the gist is that `StrongApplicative`s model some notion of "fixed size" for functors. This typeclass has an interesting connection to `Representable` functors. For reference, `Representable` is:

```hs
class Functor f => Representable x f | f -> x
  where
  rep :: f a -> (x -> a)
  unrep :: (x -> a) -> f a

instance Representable a ((->) a)
  where
  rep = id
  unrep = id
```

An [argument by @Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60610625/1726343) shows that `StrongApplicative` is a generalization of `Representable`, in that every `Representable` is `StrongApplicative`. Whether there are any `StrongApplicative`s that are not `Representable` is not yet clear.

Now, we know that `Traversable` is formulated in terms of `Applicative`, and runs in one direction. Since `StrongApplicative` promotes the `Applicative` laxities to isomorphisms, perhaps we want to use this extra equiment to invert the distributive law that `Traversable` supplies:

```hs
class Functor f => Something f
  where
  unsequence :: StrongApplicative f => f (t a) -> t (f a)
```

It just so happens that `(->) a` is a `StrongApplicative`, and in fact a representative specimen (if you'll pardon the pun) of the genus of `Representable` `StrongApplicative` functors. Hence we can write your `inject`/`promote` operation as:

```hs
promote :: Something f => (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)
promote = unsequence
```

We mentioned before that `StrongApplicative` is a superclass of the family of `Representative` functors. From examining the type of `unsequence`, it is obvious that the stronger a constraint we place on the polymorphic applicative, the easier it will be to implement `unsequence` (and hence the more instances of the resulting class).

So in a sense there is a hierarchy of "detraversable" functors that flows in the opposite direction to a hierarchy of applicative effects with respect to which you might wish to detraverse them. The hierarchy of "inner" functors would go like this:

```
Functor f => Applicative f => StrongApplicative f => Representable x f
```

And the corresponding hierarchy of detraversable/distributive functors might go like this:

```
Distributive t <= ADistributive t <= SADistributive t <= RDistributive t
```

With definitions:

```hs
class RDistributive t
  where
  rdistribute :: Representable x f => f (t a) -> t (f a)

  default rdistribute :: (SADistributive t, StrongApplicative f) => f (t a) -> t (f a)
  rdistribute = sadistribute

class RDistributive t => SADistributive t
  where
  sadistribute :: StrongApplicative f => f (t a) -> t (f a)

  default sadistribute :: (ADistributive t, Applicative f) => f (t a) -> t (f a)
  sadistribute = adistribute

class SADistributive t => ADistributive t
  where
  adistribute :: Applicative f => f (t a) -> t (f a)

  default adistribute :: (Distributive t, Functor f) => f (t a) -> t (f a)
  adistribute = distribute

class ADistributive t => Distributive t
  where
  distribute :: Functor f => f (t a) -> t (f a)
```

Our definition of `promote` can be generalized to depend on `RDistributive` (since `(->) a` itself is indeed a representable functor):

```hs
promote :: RDistributive f => (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)
promote = rdistribute
```

In a strange turn of events, once you get down to the bottom of this hierarchy (i.e. to `Distributive`), your promise of detraversability has become so strong relative to your demands that the only functors for which you can implement it are themselves `Representable`. An example of such a distributive, representable (and hence rigid) functor is that of pairs:

```hs
data Pair a = Pair { pfst :: a, psnd :: a }
  deriving Functor

instance RDistributive Pair
instance SADistributive Pair
instance ADistributive Pair
instance Distributive Pair
  where
  distribute x = Pair (pfst <$> x) (psnd <$> x)
```

Of course if you make a strong demand of the polymorphic "inner functor", for example `Representable x f` in `RDistributive`, instances like this become possible:

```hs
newtype Weird r a = Weird { runWeird :: (a -> r) -> a }
  deriving Functor

instance RDistributive (Weird r)
  where
  rdistribute = fmap unrep . promoteWeird . rep
    where
    promoteWeird :: (x -> Weird r a) -> Weird r (x -> a)
    promoteWeird f = fmap (. f) $ Weird $ \k m -> m `runWeird` \a -> k (const a)
```

TODO: Check where (if anywhere) in the hierarchy all the other examples of rigid functors fall.

As I said I haven't thought about it super carefully, so maybe the folks here that have devoted some thought to the rigid functor concept can immediately poke holes in it. Alternately, maybe it makes things fall into place that I can't yet see.

It's probably worthwhile thinking about some laws for these untraversing typeclasses. An obvious one that suggests itself is `sequence . unsequence = id` and `unsequence . sequence = id` wherever the functor supports both `Traversable` and `Untraverse`.

It's also worth mentioning that the interaction of "distributive law"s of functors with monads and comonads is quite well studied, so that might have some relevance to the monad related discussion in your posts.

Comment: "Whether there are any `StrongApplicative`s that are not `Representable` is not yet clear" -- `StrongApplicative` does imply `Representable`. `husk . unhusk = id` means `() <$ u = husk ()` for any `u`. That being so, the  shape of `husk ()` is the only possible one for a `StrongApplicative`, and having a single shape amounts to being `Representable`/`Distributive`.