# Adjoint functors determine monad transformers, but where's lift?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm intrigued by the construction described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24844388/2684007) for determining a monad transformer from adjoint functors. Here's some code that summarizes the basic idea:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import           Control.Monad

newtype Three g f m a = Three { getThree :: g (m (f a)) }

class (Functor f, Functor g) => Adjoint f g where
  counit :: f (g a) -> a
  unit   :: a -> g (f a)

instance (Adjoint f g, Monad m) => Monad (Three g f m) where
  return  = Three . fmap return . unit
  m >>= f = Three $ fmap (>>= counit . fmap (getThree . f)) (getThree m)

instance (Adjoint f g, Monad m) => Applicative (Three g f m) where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance (Adjoint f g, Monad m) => Functor (Three g f m) where
  fmap = (<*>) . pure
```

Given that `Adjoint ((,) s) ((->) s)`, `Three ((->) s) ((,) s)` appears equivalent to `StateT s`.

Very cool, but I am puzzled by a couple things:

- How can we upgrade a monadic `m a` into a monadic `Three g f m a`? For the specific case of `Three ((->) s) ((,) s)`, it's of course obvious how to do this, but it seems desirable to have a recipe that works for any `Three g f` provided that `Adjoint f g`. In other words, it seems like there should be an analog of `lift` whose definition only requires `unit`, `counit`, and the `return` and `>>=` of the input monad. But I cannot seem to find one (I have seen [a definition using `sequence`](https://github.com/ekmett/adjunctions/blob/master/src/Control/Monad/Trans/Adjoint.hs), but this seems a bit like cheating since it requires `f` to be `Traversable`).
- For that matter, how can we upgrade `g a` into a `Three g f m a` (provided `Adjoint f g`)? Again, for the specific case of `Three ((->) s) ((,) s)` it's obvious how to do this, but I'm wondering if there's an analog of `gets` that only requires `unit`, `counit`, and the `return` and `>>=` of the input monad.

Comment: N.B.: Your `(>>=)` implementation can be simplified to `m >>= f = Three $ fmap (>>= counit . fmap (getThree . f)) (getThree m)`

Comment: I have written [a follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56726854/2751851) to this question, which was originally planned as an answer here but grew too much in scope. Thanks for drawing my attention to this topic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lift`, in [Benjamin Hodgson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49325487/2751851), is set up as:

> ```
> lift mx = let mgfx = fmap unit mx
>               gmfx = distributeR mgfx
>           in Three gmfx
> -- or
> lift = Three . distributeR . fmap unit
> ```

As you know, that is not the only plausible strategy we might use there:

```
lift mx = let gfmx = unit mx
              gmfx = fmap sequenceL gfmx
          in Three gmfx
-- or
lift = Three . fmap sequenceL . unit
```

Whence the `Traversable` requirement for [Edward Kmett's corresponding `MonadTrans` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Adjoint.html#t:AdjointT) originates. The question, then, becomes whether relying on that is, as you put it, "cheating". I am going to argue it is not.

We can adapt Benjamin's game plan concerning `Distributive` and right adjoints and try to find whether left adjoints are `Traversable`. A look at [`Data.Functor.Adjunction`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html) shows we have a quite good toolbox to work with:

```
unabsurdL :: Adjunction f u => f Void -> Void
cozipL :: Adjunction f u => f (Either a b) -> Either (f a) (f b)
splitL :: Adjunction f u => f a -> (a, f ())
unsplitL :: Functor f => a -> f () -> f a
```

Edward helpfully tells us that `unabsurdL` and `cozipL` witness that "[a] left adjoint must be inhabited, [and that] a left adjoint must be inhabited by exactly one element", respectively. That, however, means `splitL` corresponds precisely to the shape-and-contents decomposition that characterises `Traversable` functors. If we add to that the fact that `splitL` and `unsplitL` are inverses, an implementation of `sequence` follows immediately:

```
sequenceL :: (Adjunction f u, Functor m) => f (m a) -> m (f a)
sequenceL = (\(mx, fu) -> fmap (\x -> unsplitL x fu) mx) . splitL
```

(Note that no more than `Functor` is demanded of `m`, as expected for traversable containers that hold exactly one value.)

All that is missing at this point is verifying that both implementations of `lift` are equivalent. That is not difficult, only a bit laborious. In a nutshell, the `distributeR` and `sequenceR` definitions here can be simplified to:

```
distributeR = \mgx ->
    leftAdjunct (\fa -> fmap (\gx -> rightAdjunct (const gx) fa) mgx) ()   
sequenceL =
    rightAdjunct (\mx -> leftAdjunct (\fu -> fmap (\x -> fmap (const x) fu) mx) ())
```

We want to show that `distributeR . fmap unit = fmap sequenceL . unit`. After a few more rounds of simplification, we get:

```
distributeR . fmap unit = \mgx ->
    leftAdjunct (\fa -> fmap (\gx -> rightAdjunct (const (unit gx)) fa) mgx) ()
fmap sequenceL . unit = \mx ->
    leftAdjunct (\fu -> fmap (\x -> fmap (const x) fu) mx) ()
```

We can show those are really the same thing by picking `\fu -> fmap (\x -> fmap (const x) fu) mx` -- the argument to `leftAdjunct` in the second right-hand side -- and slipping `rightAdjunct unit = counit . fmap unit = id` into it:

```
\fu -> fmap (\x -> fmap (const x) fu) mx
\fu -> fmap (\x -> fmap (const x) fu) mx
\fu -> fmap (\x -> (counit . fmap unit . fmap (const x)) fu) mx
\fu -> fmap (\x -> rightAdjunct (unit . const x) fu) mx
\fu -> fmap (\x -> rightAdjunct (const (unit x)) fu) mx
-- Sans variable renaming, the same as
-- \fa -> fmap (\gx -> rightAdjunct (const (unit gx)) fa) mgx
```

The takeaway is that the `Traversable` route towards your `MonadTrans` is just as secure as the `Distributive` one, and concerns about it -- including the ones mentioned by the `Control.Monad.Trans.Adjoint` documentation -- should no longer trouble anyone.

P.S.: It is worth noting that the definition of `lift` put forward here can be spelled as:

```
lift = Three . leftAdjunct sequenceL
```

That is, `lift` is `sequenceL` sent through the adjunction isomorphism. Additionally, from...

```
leftAdjunct sequenceL = distributeR . fmap unit
```

... if we apply `rightAdjunct` on both sides, we get...

```
sequenceL = rightAdjunct (distributeR . fmap unit)
```

... and if we compose `fmap (fmap counit)` on the left of both sides, we eventually end up with:

```
distributeR = leftAdjunct (fmap counit . sequenceL)
```

So `distributeR` and `sequenceL` are interdefinable.

Comment: Nice answer! Hadn't thought of doing it like that

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Incidentally, I don't think I would have recognised the shape-and-contents decomposition here if I hadn't read the topic you wrote about it on SO Documentation -- it motivated me to spend some time mulling about the matter back then.

Comment: So Docs wasn’t _entirely_ useless, then 

Answer (score 4):

> How can we upgrade a monadic `m a` into a monadic `Three g f m a`?

Good question. Time for a game of type tennis!

```
-- i'm using Adjuction from the adjunctions package because I'll need the fundeps soon
lift :: Adjunction f g => m a -> Three g f m a
lift mx = Three _
```

The hole is typed `g (m (f a))`. We have `mx :: m a` in scope, and of course `unit :: a -> g (f a)` and `fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`.

```
lift mx = let mgfx = fmap unit mx
          in Three $ _ mgfx
```

Now it's `_ :: m (g (f a)) -> g (m (f a))`. This is [`distribute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.3/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute) if `g` is [`Distributive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.3/docs/Data-Distributive.html#t:Distributive).

```
lift mx = let mgfx = fmap unit mx
              gmfx = distributeR mgfx
          in Three gmfx
-- or
lift = Three . distributeR . fmap unit
```

So now we just need to prove that the right hand side of an adjunction is always `Distributive`:

```
distributeR :: (Functor m, Adjunction f g) => m (g x) -> g (m x)
distributeR mgx = _
```

Since we need to return a `g`, the clear choice of methods from `Adjunction` is [`leftAdjunct :: Adjunction f g => (f a -> b) -> a -> g b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html#v:leftAdjunct), which uses `unit` to create a `g (f a)` and then tears down the inner `f a` by `fmap`ping a function.

```
distributeR mgx = leftAdjunct (\fa -> _) _
```

I'm going to attack the first hole first, with the expectation that filling it in might tell me something about the second one. The first hole has a type of `m a`. The only way we can get hold of an `m` of any type is by `fmap`ping something over `mgx`.

```
distributeR mgx = leftAdjunct (\fa -> fmap (\gx -> _) mgx) _
```

Now the first hole has a type of `a`, and we have `gx :: g a` in scope. If we had an `f (g a)` we could use `counit`. But we do have an `f x` (where `x` is currently an ambiguous type variable) and a `g a` in scope.

```
distributeR mgx = leftAdjunct (\fa -> fmap (\gx -> counit (fa $> gx)) mgx) _
```

It turns out that the remaining hole has an ambiguous type, so we can use anything we want. (It'll be ignored by `$>`.)

```
distributeR mgx = leftAdjunct (\fa -> fmap (\gx -> counit (fa $> gx)) mgx) ()
```

---

That derivation may have looked like a magic trick but really you just get better at type tennis with practice. The skill of the game is being able to look at the types and apply intuitions and facts about the objects you're working with. From looking at the types I could tell that I was going to need to exchange `m` and `g`, and traversing `m` was not an option (because `m` is not necessarily `Traversable`), so something like `distribute` was going to be necessary.

Besides guessing I was going to need to implement `distribute`, I was guided by some general knowledge about how adjunctions work.

Specifically, when you're talking about `* -> *`, the only interesting adjunctions are (uniquely isomorphic to) the `Reader`/`Writer` adjunction. In particular, that means any right adjoint on `Hask` is always [`Representable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Representable), as witnessed by [`tabulateAdjunction`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html#v:tabulateAdjunction) and [`indexAdjunction`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html#v:indexAdjunction). I also know that all `Representable` functors are `Distributive` (in fact logically the converse is also true, as described in [`Distributive`'s docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.3/docs/Data-Distributive.html#t:Distributive), even though the classes aren't equivalent in power), per [`distributeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#v:distributeRep).

---

> For that matter, how can we upgrade `g a` into a `Three g f m a` (provided `Adjoint f g`)?

I'll leave that as an exercise. I suspect you'll need to lean on the `g ~ ((->) s)` isomorphism again. I actually don't expect this one to be true of all adjunctions, just the ones on `Hask`, of which there is only one.

Comment: Thanks, I had gotten as far as the needing-to-distribute step, but I know less about `Distributive` things than `Traversables`, and so had gotten stuck there. In re: "What makes you think this is possible?" Well, if the only interesting right adjoints in Hask are isomorphic to Reader, and `Monad m => g a -> Three g f m a` is straightforward to characterize with a Reader-y `g`, you might expect this to be possible. Or have I gotten confused?

Comment: @SimonC Yes I think you're right actually, I was actually in the process of removing that sentence while you posted that comment :). I expect it to be straightforward to implement once you're tooled up with `tabulateAdjunction` and `indexAdjunction`.

Comment: Thanks. This makes my second SO question in which you've kindly pointed me towards `Distributive`! :) To be clear: do you expect the `lift` recipe to work for all adjunctions or just ones on Hask?

Comment: Someone like Ed Kmett would be much better positioned to answer that authoritatively than I am. My intuition goes something like this: given that every monad is generated by an adjunction (just not necessarily an adjunction on Hask), it wouldn't surprise me in the slightest if every monad _transformer_ was also generated by an adjunction.

Comment: In fact that does appear to be true, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515876/is-there-a-monad-that-doesnt-have-a-corresponding-monad-transformer-except-io

Comment: I agree it seems true. It isn't exactly a proof, but the fact that `return` and `>>=` for `Three g f m` are constructed using only `fmap`s, `unit`, `counit`, and `return`/`join` (none of which is in principle Hask-specific) made me think the transformer construction was totally general. It was less clear to me that the existence of a `lift` recipe should be, since it was not obvious to me that the ability to transform a monadic `m` to a monadic `t m` absolutely implied the existence of a `lift` recipe when the adjoint functors don't live entirely in Hask.

Comment: For me, the main question is - how do I find the monad transformer for a given base monad. I think the construction with `Adjoint f g` will not work in general, because we won't be able to find any adjoint `Hask` endofunctors `f`, `g` such that their composition is equal to a given monad. An example monad for which this monad transformer is (I believe) unavailable: `type L z a = Either a (z -> a)`, where `z` is a fixed type. `return= Left` and `bind` can be defined, laws hold, but a monad transformer for L (I believe) can't be found with the adjoint recipe.

Comment: @winitzki I have written [a follow-up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56726854/2751851) that attempts to tackle the more general problem. As for your type, in a way it depends on what you want for the transformer. On the one hand, bolting on effects to both sides of the `Either` does look hard-to-impossible; on the other hand. `newtype LM z a = Ready a | Waiting (r -> m a)` is a perfectly good transformer on its own.

Comment: @duplode Thank you for an interesting follow-up. I've been busy finding the monad transformer for the construction of "free pointed" monad over a given monad `g`:  I define `type L g a = Either a (g a)`, and I checked that `L g` is a lawful monad if `g` is one. If `t m` is a monad transformer for `g` (with foreign monad `m`) then I think that `g (Either a (t m a))` is the monad transformer for `L`. I have not finished the calculations, but this seems promising. Your `LM` corresponds to `Either a (t m a)`, but this violates transformer laws (`m a -> Either a (t m a)` is not monad-preserving).

Comment: @winitzki Good catch about the `return` transformer law for `LM`! Interestingly, there was [a discussion about an analogous situation in the *pipes* issue tracker](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Library/issues/179) a while ago.

Comment: Note that `g (Either a (t m a))` wraps your `LM` in an additional layer of `g`. Very similarly, the "correct" ListT and FreeT transformers must add an additional monad layer on the outside. I would be interested to know whether this somehow follows from any construction with adjunctions.

Comment: @duplode I have been looking systematically for monads whose transformer composes outside of the foreign monad. The `Reader` monad is one example, but I have found a wider class of monads with this property, which I call "rigid" monads. They are not `Distributive`, in general. For example, if `p` is a fixed type and `R` is defined by `type R a = (a -> p) -> a` then `R` is a rigid monad whose transformer works on a foreign monad `m` as `t m a = (m a -> p) -> m a`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649497/is-this-property-of-a-functor-stronger-than-a-monad for my post on rigid functors.

Comment: @winitzki Ooh, nice! While I had read that post three years ago (as the upvote markers tell me), I didn't understand the problem well enough back then to fully appreciate the implications. This notion of rigidity plays right into some experiments I have been doing lately with `Distributive`, though I hadn't succeeded in identifying anything like another step in the class hierarchy. I will think a bit more about this and then comment on your question later.