# Juggling existentials without unsafeCoerce

Tags: haskell, existential-type, higher-rank-types

Lately I have been playing with this type, which I understand to be an encoding of the free distributive functor (for tangential background on that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822105/2751851)):

```
data Ev g a where
    Ev :: ((g x -> x) -> a) -> Ev g a

deriving instance Functor (Ev g)
```

The existential constructor ensures I can only consume an `Ev g` by supplying a polymorphic extractor `forall x. g x -> x`, and that the lift and lower functions of the free construction can be given compatible types:

```
runEv :: Ev g a -> (forall x. g x -> x) -> a
runEv (Ev s) f = s f

evert :: g a -> Ev g a
evert u = Ev $ \f -> f u

revert :: Distributive g => Ev g a -> g a
revert (Ev s) = s <$> distribute id
```

However, there is a difficulty upon trying to give `Ev g` a `Distributive` instance. Given that `Ev g` is ultimately just a function with a weird argument type, one might hope that just threading `distribute` for functions (which amounts to `(??) :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b` [from *lens*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-), and doesn't inspect the argument type in any way) through the `Ev` wrapper:

```
instance Distributive (Ev g) where
    distribute = Ev . distribute . fmap (\(Ev s) -> s)
```

That, however, does not work:

```
Flap3.hs:95:53: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘x0’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          Ev :: forall (g :: * -> *) x a. ((g x -> x) -> a) -> Ev g a,
        in a lambda abstraction
        at Flap3.hs:95:44-47
      Expected type: (g x0 -> x0) -> a
        Actual type: (g x -> x) -> a
    • In the expression: s
      In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(\ (Ev s) -> s)’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘fmap (\ (Ev s) -> s)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        s :: (g x -> x) -> a (bound at Flap3.hs:95:47)
   |
95 |     distribute = Ev . distribute . fmap (\(Ev s) -> s) 
   |                                                     ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

GHC objects to rewrapping the existential, even though we do nothing untoward with it between unwrapping and rewrapping. The only way out I found was resorting to `unsafeCoerce`:

```
instance Distributive (Ev g) where
    distribute = Ev . distribute . fmap (\(Ev s) -> unsafeCoerce s)
```

Or, spelling it in a perhaps more cautious manner:

```
instance Distributive (Ev g) where
    distribute = eevee . distribute . fmap getEv
        where
        getEv :: Ev g a -> (g Any -> Any) -> a
        getEv (Ev s) = unsafeCoerce s
        eevee :: ((g Any -> Any) -> f a) -> Ev g (f a)
        eevee s = Ev (unsafeCoerce s)
```

Is it possible to get around this problem without `unsafeCoerce`? or there truly is no other way?

Additional remarks:

- I believe `Ev` is the most correct type I can give to the construction, though I would be happy to be proved wrong. All my attempts to shift the quantifiers elsewhere lead either to needing `unsafeCoerce` somewhere else or to `evert` and `revert` having types that don't allow them to be composed.
- This situation looks, at first glance, similar to the one described in [this blog post by Sandy Maguire](https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/existentials/), which ends up sticking with `unsafeCoerce` as well.

---

The following take at giving `Ev g` a `Representable` instance might put the problem into sharper relief. [As dfeuer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828434/2751851), this isn't really supposed to be possible; unsurprisingly, I had to use `unsafeCoerce` again:

```
-- Cf. dfeuer's answer.
newtype Goop g = Goop { unGoop :: forall y. g y -> y }

instance Representable (Ev g) where
    type Rep (Ev g) = Goop g
    tabulate f = Ev $ \e -> f (Goop (goopify e))
        where
        goopify :: (g Any -> Any) -> g x -> x
        goopify = unsafeCoerce
    index (Ev s) = \(Goop e) -> s e
```

While `goopify` sure looks alarming, I think there is a case for it being safe here. The existential encoding means any `e` that gets passed to the wrapped function will necessarily be an extractor polymorphic on the element type, that gets specialised to `Any` merely because I asked for that to happen. That being so, `forall x. g x -> x` is a sensible type for `e`. This dance of specialising to `Any` only to promptly undo it with `unsafeCoerce` is needed because GHC forces me to get rid of the existential by making a choice. This is what happens if I leave out the `unsafeCoerce` in this case:

```
Flap4.hs:64:37: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘y’ with ‘x0’
      ‘y’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall y. g y -> y
        at Flap4.hs:64:32-37
      Expected type: g y -> y
        Actual type: g x0 -> x0
    • In the first argument of ‘Goop’, namely ‘e’
      In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘(Goop e)’
      In the expression: f (Goop e)
    • Relevant bindings include
        e :: g x0 -> x0 (bound at Flap4.hs:64:24)
   |
64 |     tabulate f = Ev $ \e -> f (Goop e) 
   |                                     ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

---

Prolegomena needed to run the code here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Distributive
import Data.Functor.Rep
import Unsafe.Coerce
import GHC.Exts (Any)

-- A tangible distributive, for the sake of testing.
data Duo a = Duo { fstDuo :: a, sndDuo :: a }
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor)

instance Distributive Duo where
    distribute u = Duo (fstDuo <$> u) (sndDuo <$> u)
```

Comment: "The existential constructor ensures I can only consume an `Ev g` by supplying a polymorphic extractor" Perhaps you could make that more explicit, like `Ev :: ((forall x . g x -> x) -> a) -> Ev g a`. Such definition makes the definition `distribute wrapped = Ev (\f -> fmap (\(Ev z) -> z f) wrapped) ` compile for me, although it breaks the generic deriving of `Functor` for some reason.

Comment: @danidiaz The problem with doing it that way is that it stops `revert` from typechecking, as `distribute id :: g (g a -> a)` won't be polymorphic enough to map the wrapped function over it.

Comment: Is `fmap (\(Ev s) -> s)` really something sensible to do? The object you are `fmap`-ing over could contain many `Ev` (say, `fmap = map`), each with its own existentially quantified `x`.

Comment: For reference, the foolproof, (almost-)certainly-correct free `Distributive` is `Ev g a = (forall g'. Distributive g' => (forall x. g x -> g' x) -> g' a)`, but I don't think that helps in making your `Ev` work.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I think it is sensible. `x` does not appear in a "strictly positive" position, so it seems that any such differences won't be observable. For instance `[Ev (\e -> show . e $ Duo 1 2), Ev (\e -> e $ Duo "foo" "bar")]` typechecks as `Ev Duo String` and works just fine. (Note that I must straighten out the result types of the suspensions to `String`.)

Comment: @HTNW Yup -- that would be the final form, if my terminology is right. It does seem to be isomorphic to `Ev`: `toEvFinal (Ev s) = EvFinal $ \n -> revert (Ev (s . (. n)))` and `fromEvFinal (EvFinal s) = s evert`.

Comment: I think it's just as good to use @danidiaz's representation with `unsafeCoerce` in `revert`. This avoids using `data` to wrap a function. As you say, `distribute id :: forall x. g (g x -> x)` is insufficiently polymorphic, but you can do the same thing: specialize to `x ~ Any` and coerce under the `fmap`.

Comment: @DanielWagner The `x`es are behind a function arrow, so the secretly wrapped values aren't really of `x` type; they merely dictate a specialisation of a polymorphic `x`. The customary trick is to encode existential quantification with universal quantification. If I understand it correctly, I have done it twice here, which would make it become universal again.

Comment: @dfeuer Well-spotted! It seems another advantage of doing it this way is that it reduces the number of places `unsafeCoerce` is necessary, assuming there really is no way to get rid of it altogether. Auspiciously, neither the `Distributive` instance nor the `Representable` one requires a further `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: @danidiaz Your intuition was sound after all. I thank both you and dfeuer for my self-answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestions by danidiaz and dfeuer have led me to a tidier encoding, though `unsafeCoerce` is still necessary:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Unsafe.Coerce
import GHC.Exts (Any)
import Data.Distributive
import Data.Functor.Rep

-- Px here stands for "polymorphic extractor".
newtype Px g = Px { runPx :: forall x. g x -> x }

newtype Ev g a = Ev { getEv :: Px g -> a }
    deriving Functor

runEv :: Ev g a -> (forall x. g x -> x) -> a
runEv s e = s `getEv` Px e

evert :: g a -> Ev g a
evert u = Ev $ \e -> e `runPx` u

revert :: Distributive g => Ev g a -> g a
revert (Ev s) = (\e -> s (mkPx e)) <$> distribute id
    where
    mkPx :: (g Any -> Any) -> Px g
    mkPx e = Px (unsafeCoerce e) 

instance Distributive (Ev g) where
    distribute = Ev . distribute . fmap getEv

instance Representable (Ev g) where
    type Rep (Ev g) = Px g
    tabulate = Ev 
    index = getEv
```

The `x` variable in my original formulation of `Ev` was, at heart, being universally quantified; I had merely disguised it as an existential behind a function arrow. While that encoding makes it possible to write `revert` without `unsafeCoerce`, it shifts the burden to the instance implementations. Directly using universal quantification is ultimately better in this case, as it keeps the magic concentrated in one place.

The `unsafeCoerce` trick here is essentially the same demonstrated with `tabulate` in the question: the `x` in `distribute id :: Distributive g => g (g x -> x)` is specialised to `Any`, and then the specialisation is immediately undone, under the `fmap`, with `unsafeCoerce`. I believe the trick is safe, as I have sufficient control over what is being fed to `unsafeCoerce`.

As for getting rid of `unsafeCoerce`, I truly can't see a way. Part of the problem is that it seems I would need some form of impredicative types, as the `unsafeCoerce` trick ultimately amounts to turning `forall x. g (g x -> x)` into `g (forall x. g x -> x)`. For the sake of comparison, I can write a vaguely analogous, if much simpler, scenario using the subset of the impredicative types functionality that would fall under the scope of the mooted `ExplicitImpredicativeTypes` extension (see [GHC ticket #14859](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14859) and links therein for discussion):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Foo = Foo ([forall x. Num x => x] -> Int)

testFoo :: Applicative f => Foo -> f Int
testFoo (Foo f) = fmap @_ @[forall x. Num x => x] f 
    $ pure @_ @[forall x. Num x => x] [1,2,3]
```

```
GHCi> :set -XImpredicativeTypes 
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications 
GHCi> testFoo @Maybe (Foo length)
Just 3
```

`distribute id`, however, is thornier than `[1,2,3]`. In `id :: g x -> g x`, the type variable I'd like to keep quantified appears in two places, with one of them being the second type argument to `distribute` (the `(->) (g x)` functor). To my untrained eye at least, that looks utterly intractable.

Comment: The only open question, I think, is whether `distribute` with something other than reader could somehow do the trick.... Seems unlikely, but I dunno how to demonstrate it's impossible.

Comment: @dfeuer At times, I have wondered if there might be an alternative encoding of the free distributive/representable that would allow for something different -- which sounds similarly unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Every `Distributive` functor can be made `Representable`, though we can't prove that in Haskell (I imagine it's not constructive). But one approach to addressing your problem is to just switch classes.

```
newtype Evv f a = Evv
  {unEvv :: forall g. Representable g
         => (forall x. f x -> g x) -> g a}

instance Functor (Evv g) where
  fmap f (Evv q) = Evv $ \g -> fmap f (q g)

evert :: g a -> Evv g a
evert ga = Evv $ \f -> f ga

revert :: Representable g => Evv g a -> g a
revert (Evv f) = f id

newtype Goop f = Goop
  {unGoop :: forall x. f x -> x}

instance Distributive (Evv g) where
  collect = collectRep

instance Representable (Evv g) where
  type Rep (Evv g) = Goop g
  tabulate f = Evv $ \g -> fmap (\rg -> f (Goop $ \fx -> index (g fx) rg)) $ tabulate id
  index (Evv g) (Goop z) = runIdentity $ g (Identity . z)
```

I haven't yet tried this with `Distributive` directly (as HTNW suggests), but I wouldn't be surprised if it were simply impossible for some reason.

Warning: I have not proven that this is actually the free `Representable`!

Comment: This is not the same type?

Comment: This raises a relevant point: what I'm trying to do might perhaps be described as an attempt to conjure the representation for `Distributive` in Haskell. My type is, in spirit, `Goop g -> a`, though the quantifiers make a mess of it all. I have just attempted to write `Representable (Ev g)` for my type, with `Rep (Ev g) = Goop g`, and guess what: I needed `unsafeCoerce` for writing `tabulate`. It seems to work, though I'm slightly less certain of the soundness of this instance.

Comment: @AndrásKovács It is a different encoding, which sans the change of constraint is, as far as I can tell, [isomorphic to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826733/juggling-existentials-without-unsafecoerce#comment100209268_56826733).

Comment: @duplode I don't see how the original `Ev g` is representable. For many choices of `g`, `Ev g a` can contain anywhere from zero to infinite number of `a`s, e.g. if `g = []`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács If `g ~ []`, `Ev g a` will contain no (observable) `a`s, because strictly speaking there are no `[a] -> a` functions.

Comment: @duplode I was thinking about strong sigma types, but I think you're right in the current case with the weird weak existential elimination.

Comment: @duplode, for what it's worth, my type is just a convoluted version of the one danidiaz suggests: `newtype Ev g a = Ev ((forall x . g x -> x) -> a)`. What you won't like is that `revert` sure seems to need a `Representable` constraint.