# Are all fixed size containers strong monoidal functors, and/or vice versa?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, category-theory

The `Applicative` typeclass represents lax monoidal functors that preserve the cartesian monoidal structure on the category of typed functions.

In other words, given the canonical isomorphisms witnessing that `(,)` forms a monoidal structure:

```hs
-- Implementations left to the motivated reader
assoc_fwd :: ((a, b), c) -> (a, (b, c))
assoc_bwd :: (a, (b, c)) -> ((a, b), c)

lunit_fwd :: ((), a) -> a
lunit_bwd :: a -> ((), a)

runit_fwd :: (a, ()) -> a
runit_bwd :: a -> (a, ())
```

The typeclass and its laws can equivalently be written like this:

```hs
class Functor f => Applicative f
  where
  zip :: (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
  husk :: () -> f ()

-- Laws:

-- assoc_fwd >>> bimap id zip >>> zip
-- =
-- bimap zip id >>> zip >>> fmap assoc_fwd

-- lunit_fwd
-- =
-- bimap husk id >>> zip >>> fmap lunit_fwd

-- runit_fwd
-- =
-- bimap id husk >>> zip >>> fmap runit_fwd
```

One might wonder what a functor that is *oplax* monoidal with respect to the same structure might look like:

```hs
class Functor f => OpApplicative f
  where
  unzip :: f (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
  unhusk :: f () -> ()

-- Laws:

-- assoc_bwd <<< bimap id unzip <<< unzip
-- =
-- bimap unzip id <<< unzip <<< fmap assoc_bwd

-- lunit_bwd
-- =
-- bimap unhusk id <<< unzip <<< fmap lunit_bwd

-- runit_bwd
-- =
-- bimap id unhusk <<< unzip <<< fmap runit_bwd
```

If we think about the types involved in the definitions and laws, the disappointing truth is revealed; `OpApplicative` is no more specific a constraint than `Functor`:

```hs
instance Functor f => OpApplicative f
  where
  unzip fab = (fst <$> fab, snd <$> fab)
  unhusk = const ()
```

However, while every `Applicative` functor (really, any `Functor`) is trivially `OpApplicative`, there is not necessarily a nice relationship between the `Applicative` laxities and `OpApplicative` oplaxities. So we  can look for *strong monoidal* functors wrt the cartesian monoidal structure:

```hs
class (Applicative f, OpApplicative f) => StrongApplicative f

-- Laws:
-- unhusk . husk = id
-- husk . unhusk = id
-- zip . unzip = id
-- unzip . zip = id
```

The first law above is trivial, since the only inhabitant of the type `() -> ()` is the identity function on `()`.

However, the remaining three laws, and hence the subclass itself, is *not* trivial. Specifically, not every `Applicative` is a lawful instance of this class.

Here are some `Applicative` functors for which we can declare lawful instances of `StrongApplicative`:

- `Identity`
- `VoidF`
- `(->) r`
- <strike>`Monoid m => (,) m`</strike> (see answers)
- `Vec (n :: Nat)`
- `Stream` (infinite)

And here are some `Applicative`s for which we cannot:

- `[]`
- `Either e`
- `Maybe`
- `NonEmptyList`

The pattern here suggests that the `StrongApplicative` class is in a sense the `FixedSize` class, where "fixed size" <sup>*</sup> means that the multiplicity <sup>**</sup> of inhabitants of `a` in an inhabitant of `f a` is fixed.

This can be stated as two conjectures:

- Every `Applicative` representing a "fixed size" container of elements of its type argument is an instance of `StrongApplicative`
- No instance of `StrongApplicative` exists in which the number of occurrences of `a` can vary

Can anyone think of counterexamples that disprove these conjectures, or some convincing reasoning that demonstrates why they are true or false?

---

* I realize that I haven't properly defined the adjective "fixed size". Unfortunately the task is a little bit circular. I don't know of any formal description of a "fixed size" container, and am trying to come up with one. `StrongApplicative` is my best attempt so far.

In order to evaluate whether this is a good definition however, I need something to compare it to. Given some formal/informal definition of what it means for a functor to have a given size or multiplicity with respect to inhabitants of its type argument, the question is whether the existence of a `StrongApplicative` instance precisely distinguishes functors of fixed and varying size.

Not being aware of an existing formal definition, I'm making an appeal to intuition in my usage of the term "fixed size". However if someone already knows of an existing formalism for the size of a functor and can compare `StrongApplicative` to it, so much the better.

** By "multiplicity" I'm referring in a loose sense to "how many" arbitrary elements of the functor's parameter type occur in an inhabitant of the functor's codomain type. This is *without* regard to the specific type the functor is applied to, and hence without regard to any specific inhabitants of the parameter type.

Not being precise about this has caused some confusion in the comments, so here's some examples of what I would consider the size/multiplicity of various functors to be:

- `VoidF`: fixed, 0
- `Identity`: fixed, 1
- `Maybe`: variable, minimum 0, maximum 1
- `[]`: variable, minimum 0, maximum infinite
- `NonEmptyList`: variable, minimum 1, maximum infinite
- `Stream`: fixed, infinite
- `Monoid m => (,) m`: fixed, 1
- `data Pair a = Pair a a`: fixed, 2
- `Either x`: variable, minimum 0, maximum 1
- `data Strange a = L a | R a`: fixed, 1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209288/discussion-on-question-by-asad-saeeduddin-are-all-fixed-size-containers-strong-m).

Comment: One possible definition of "fixed size" would be "representable". All representable functors are strong applicatives in the sense described here, because `(->) r` is and they're isomorphic in the right way to that.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think you need more than just an isomorphism in order to inherit the strong applicative from `(->) r`; you need the components of the isomorphism to preserve the strong applicative structure. For some reason the `Representable` typeclass in Haskell has a mysterious `tabulate . return = return` law (which doesn't really even make sense for non monadic functors), but it gives us 1/4 of the conditions we need to say that `tabulate` and `zip` are morphisms of a suitable category of monoids. The other 3 are extra laws you have to demand.

Comment: Sorry, that should be "`tabulate` and `index` are morphisms of a suitable category..."

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin The way that law is stated in the docs is oddly specific, perhaps, but it turns out requiring `return` isn't a serious problem. `cotraverse getConst . Const` is a default implementation for `return`/`pure` in terms of `Distributive`, and, since distributives/representables have fixed shape, that implementation is unique.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin *If* you already have a strong applicative structure, than merely having an isomorphism isn't enough, indeed. But if your question is "does there exist a strong applicative structure?", then that can be answered with any isomorphism; the isomorphism, plus the strong applicative structure on `(->) r`, induces a strong applicative structure on the representable functor (though perhaps not The One you had in mind if you already had one in mind!). Since this gives a way to construct a strong applicative structure, this answers the question in the affirmative.

Comment: Possibly worth considering: moving from `pure :: a -> f a` to `husk :: () -> f ()` is okay for `Applicative` because we already have `Functor`, and so we can implement `pure a = a <$ husk ()`. But are you sure that the analogous move from `impure :: f a -> a` to `unhusk :: f () -> ()` is okay?

Comment: @DanielWagner Why wouldn’t it be?

Comment: @bradrn Well... I guess I left that a bit implied, but... the first move is okay because we can implement `pure` in terms of `husk`. But we can't implement `impure` in terms of `unhusk`. So it seems weird that the two ways of defining `Applicative` turn out to be the same, but when we "turn the arrows around", we get two ways of defining `OpApplicative` that are *not* the same. That seems like a hint that we haven't worked out the right way to "turn the arrows around" yet. Perhaps related: we demand `Functor => Applicative`, but not `OpFunctor => OpApplicative`. Why (not)?

Comment: @DanielWagner Good observation — I understand now. But if this is the ‘wrong’ way of flipping the arrows, then what is the right way? As for not demanding `OpFunctor => OpApplicative`, it’s because Haskell `OpFunctor` is the same as `Functor`: `opfmap :: OpFunctor f => (b -> a) -> f (b -> a)` is equivalent to `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f (a -> b)`.

Comment: @bradrn Are you sure? Another way to turn the arrow around, more consistent with how `zip` was flipped, would be to transition from `fmap :: (a -> b, f a) -> f b` to `opfmap :: f b -> (a -> b, f a)` or something! Anyway, just to say: I'm not sure I know what the right way to do this is, hence my proposal that the person asking the question ponder deeply and clarify, though of course I also keep thinking about it a bit myself.

Comment: @DanielWagner That’s a pretty interesting definition, and one I hadn’t thought of before. I suppose another way to do it is `contramap :: Contravariant => (a -> b) -> f b -> f a`. I think I’ll keep on thinking about this myself as well.

Comment: @DanielWagner Sorry, I still disagree that a functor `f` with an arbitrary natural isomorphism to a strong applicative functor `g` (in this case `(->) (Rep r)`) equips `f` with an applicative structure. Unless the components of the isomorphism preserve applicative structure (which is not trivial), there is no guarantee that your derived applicative for `f` is a lawful applicative.

Comment: What you are claiming is analogous to claiming that if you have some monoid `(m :: *, append :: m -> m -> m, mempty :: m)` and a bijection `(f :: m -> n, g :: n -> m)`, then you can derive a monoid structure on `n`. But you can only do this if the bijection is more than just a bijection. It needs to be a monoid isomorphism that preserves the monoid structure.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin It is analogous, and that other claim is true, too: a bijection on a set which has monoid structure induces monoid structure on the other side of the bijection. There is no need for the bijection to "preserve the monoid structure" -- it is a consequence that you can prove after-the-fact that the bijection is *also* a monoid isomorphism between the original monoid and the induced monoid, but that's basically irrelevant to the question of whether the other thing we made up is a monoid or not.

Comment: @DanielWagner Do you have somewhere I can refer to a proof of this? I believe it in the case that the bijection is a monoid isomorphism, but if it is not a monoid isomorphism I don't understand how it could be true. Unless you're claiming every bijection out of a monoid is a monoid isomorphism for some monoid on the other set.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I am claiming exactly that, yes. It's really not that hard to prove yourself. Take `(M, +, 0)` as your monoid, `f : M -> N` and `g : N -> M` any bijection. Define `n1 * n2 = f (g n1 + g n2)` and `1 = f 0`. Then `(N, *, 1)` is a monoid: `(n1 * n2) * n3 = f (g (f (g n1 + g n2)) + g n3) = f ((g n1 + g n2) + g n3) = f (g n1 + (g n2 + g n3)) = f (g n1 + g (f (g n2 + g n3))) = n1 * (n2 * n3)`, and `1 * n = f (g (f 0) + g n) = f (0 + g n) = f (g n) = n`, and `n * 1 = f (g n + g (f 0)) = f (g n + 0) = f (g n) = n`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin ...and `f`, `g` are a monoid isomorphism: `f 0 = 1`, `f m1 * f m2 = f (g (f m1) + g (f m2)) = f (m1 + m2)`, `g 1 = g (f 0) = 0`, `g n1 + g n2 = g (f (g n1 + g n2)) = g (n1 * n2)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's pretty surprising to me. I tried out one of the Applicative laws and to my surprise it all just decomposes: https://gist.github.com/masaeedu/9c25b89594a2417f6668d2dd00fbcbba

Comment: @DanielWagner Regarding the `pure` and `husk` thing; from my perspective I'm actually treating the abstract concept of an "lax/oplax/strong monoidal functor" as the central one and `Applicative` as just the Haskell-ism that loosely models it. From that perspective `husk` and `unhusk` are exactly the morphisms an (op)lax monoidal functor needs to supply, and no more.

Comment: Regarding "but not `OpFunctor => OpApplicative`", `OpFunctor` is trivial. Every functor `C -> D` gives rise to its opposite functor `C^op -> D^op`, whose morphism and object mappings are actually identical to the original functor. `OpApplicative` is actually precisely the claim that our `Functor`'s opposite is lax monoidal, which happens to be trivial in `Hask`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Every `Applicative` representing a "fixed size" container of elements of its type argument is an instance of `StrongApplicative`
> - No instance of `StrongApplicative` exists in which the number of occurrences of `a` can vary
>
> Can anyone think of counterexamples that disprove these conjectures,
>   or some convincing reasoning that demonstrates why they are true or
>   false?

I’m not sure about that first conjecture, and based on discussions with @AsadSaeeduddin it’s likely to be difficult to prove, but the second conjecture is true. To see why, consider the `StrongApplicative` law `husk . unhusk == id`; that is, for all `x :: f ()`, `husk (unhusk x) == x`. But in Haskell, `unhusk == const ()`, so that law is equivalent to saying for all `x :: f ()`, `husk () == x`. But this in turn implies that there can only exist one distinct value of type `f ()`: if there were two values `x, y :: f ()`, then `x == husk ()` and `husk () == y`, so `x == y`. But if there is only one possible `f ()` value, then `f` must be of fixed shape. (e.g. for `data Pair a = Pair a a`, there is only one value of type `Pair ()`, this being `Pair () ()`, but there are multiple values of type `Maybe ()` or `[()]`.) Thus `husk . unhusk == id` implies that `f` must be of fixed shape.

Comment: Hm. Is it really clear that "there can only exist one distinct value of type `f ()`" implies "the number of occurrences of `a` can not vary" in the presence of fancy GADTs and stuff?

Comment: @DanielWagner It turned out that “the number of occurrences of `a` cannot vary” isn’t a sufficient condition for a `StrongApplicative` instance; for instance, `data Writer w a = Writer (w,a)` has non-varying multiplicity of `a`, but is not a `StrongApplicative`. You actually need the shape of the functor to be invariant, which I do believe is a consequence of `f ()` being a singleton.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that's relevant. In the answer, while confirming the second conjecture, you argue that "strong applicative" implies "one distinct `f ()`" implies "number of occurrences of `a` can not vary". I am objecting that the last step of that argument is not clearly true; e.g. consider `data Weird a where One :: a -> Weird a; None :: Weird Bool`. There is a distinct value of type `Weird ()`, but different constructors have varying numbers of `a`s inside. (It's not a full counterexample here because `Functor` is hard, but how do we know that can't be fixed?)

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point that `Weird ()` is a singleton but it is not of fixed shape. But `Weird` isn’t a `Functor`, so it cannot be a `StrongApplicative` anyway. I suppose the relevant conjecture would be: _if `f` is a `Functor`, does `f ()` being a singleton imply that `f` is of fixed shape_? I strongly suspect this to be true, but as you have noted I don’t actually have any proof yet.

Answer (score 5):

We can answer at least one of these questions in the negative:

> Every Applicative representing a "fixed size" container of elements of its type argument is an instance of StrongApplicative

In fact one of the examples of a lawful `StrongApplicative` in the original question is wrong. The writer applicative `Monoid => (,) m` is not `StrongApplicative`, because for example `husk $ unhusk $ ("foo", ()) == ("", ()) /= ("foo", ())`.

Similarly, the example of a fixed size container:

```
data Strange a = L a | R a
```

of fixed multiplicity 1, is not a strong applicative, because if we define `husk = Left` then `husk $ unhusk $ Right () /= Right ()`, and vice versa. An equivalent way to view this is that this is just the writer applicative for your choice of monoid on `Bool`.

So there exist "fixed size" applicatives that are not `StrongApplicative`. Whether all `StrongApplicative`s are of fixed size remains to be seen.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take representable functors as our definition of "fixed size container":

```
class Representable f where
    type Rep f
    tabulate :: (Rep f -> a) -> f a
    index :: f a -> Rep f -> a
```

The real `Representable` has a few laws and superclasses, but for the purposes of this answer, we actually need just two properties:

```
tabulate . index = id
index . tabulate = id
```

(Okay, we also need a law-abiding `instance StrongApplicative ((->) r)`. Easy peasy, you already agree it exists.)

If we take that definition, then I can confirm that conjecture 1:

> Every `Applicative` representing a "fixed size" container of elements of its type argument is an [law-abiding] instance of `StrongApplicative`

is true. Here's how:

```
instance Representable f => Applicative f where
    zip (fa, fb) = tabulate (zip (index fa, index fb))
    husk = tabulate . husk

instance Representable f => OpApplicative f where
    unzip fab = let (fa, fb) = unzip (index fab) in (tabulate fa, tabulate fb)
    unhusk = unhusk . index

instance Representable f => StrongApplicative f
```

There's a lot of laws to prove, but I'll focus just on the Big Four that `StrongApplicative` add -- you probably already believe the lead-in ones for `Applicative` and `OpApplicative`, but if you don't, their proofs look just like the ones below (which in turn look quite a lot like each other). For clarity, I will use `zipf`, `huskf`, etc. for the function instance, and `zipr`, `huskr`, etc. for the representable instance, so you can keep track of which is which. (And so that it's easy to verify that we don't take the thing we're trying to prove as an assumption! It's okay to use `unhuskf . huskf = id` when proving `unhuskr . huskr = id`, but it would be wrong to assume `unhuskr . huskr = id` in that same proof.)

The proof of each law proceeds in basically the same way: unroll definitions, drop the isomorphism that `Representable` gives you, then use the analogous law for functions.

```
unhuskr . huskr
= { def. of unhuskr and huskr }
(unhuskf . index) . (tabulate . huskf)
= { index . tabulate = id }
unhuskf . huskf
= { unhuskf . huskf = id }
id

huskr . unhuskr
= { def. of huskr and unhuskr }
(tabulate . huskf) . (unhuskf . index)
= { huskf . unhuskf = id }
tabulate . index
= { tabulate . index = id }
id

zipr (unzipr fab)
= { def. of unzipr }
zipr (let (fa, fb) = unzipf (index fab) in (tabulate fa, tabulate fb))
= { def. of zipr }
let (fa, fb) = unzipf (index fab) in tabulate (zipf (index (tabulate fa), index (tabulate fb)))
= { index . tabulate = id }
let (fa, fb) = unzipf (index fab) in tabulate (zipf (fa, fb))
= { def. of (fa, fb) }
tabulate (zipf (unzipf (index fab)))
= { zipf . unzipf = id }
tabulate (index fab)
= { tabulate . index = id }
fab

unzipr (zipr (fa, fb))
= { def. of zipr }
unzipr (tabulate (zipf (index fa, index fb)))
= { def. of unzipr }
let (fa', fb') = unzipf (index (tabulate (zipf (index fa, index fb))))
in (tabulate fa', tabulate fb')
= { index . tabulate = id }
let (fa', fb') = unzipf (zipf (index fa, index fb))
in (tabulate fa', tabulate fb')
= { unzipf . zipf = id }
let (fa', fb') = (index fa, index fb)
in (tabulate fa', tabulate fb')
= { def. of fa' and fb' }
(tabulate (index fa), tabulate (index fb))
= { tabulate . index = id }
(fa, fb)
```

Comment: Currently pondering: `instance StrongApplicative f => Representable f where type Rep f = forall x. f x -> x`. `index` is easy. I haven't worked out the trick for `tabulate` yet, but it seems tantalizingly close.

Comment: In discussion with @AsadSaeeduddin, I managed to find this same `StrongApplicative` instance as well, but couldn’t prove the laws. Congratulations for figuring it out! I tried to do the `Representable` instance as well given `StrongApplicative`, but couldn’t think of a good `Rep` type — I’d be curious to know, how does your `forall x. f x -> x` achieve this?

Comment: @bradrn Recall that the hypothesis is that these things have a fixed set of "holes" into which elements slot. Then the functions of type `forall x. f x -> x` are exactly those functions which choose a hole and return the value in that hole. (And, while thinking about how to implement `tabulate`, I have come up with an objection to the type for `unhusk`; see comments on the question itself for details.)

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner! That’s a really clever approach — I wouldn’t have thought of that.

Comment: After trying to implement it, I don’t think I’m convinced that `forall x. f x -> x` will work as `Rep`. My reasoning is that, using this `Rep`, you can write `index` for _any_ type, not just `StrongApplicative` ones — so I suspect that `forall x. f x -> x` might be too general.

Comment: @bradrn Indeed, the trick is getting your hands on a suitable `f (forall x. f x -> x)` to implement `tabulate` with. And now you can start to see why I might want to demand `unhusk :: f x -> x` (...or similar...) instead of `unhusk :: f () -> ()`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with a lot of the points in here, but unfortunately I actually don't "already believe the lead-in ones for" `Applicative` and `OpApplicative`, at least not unless you place additional constraints on `tabulate` and `zip`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Hm, okay, that stance surprises me a bit. Which law did you have trouble proving in the same way as above? I'm not going to write out the same boring "unroll definitions, apply underlying law" pattern six more times. Perhaps the blocker is that I didn't include the `instance Representable f => Functor f where fmap fab = tabulate . fmap fab . index` definition (I thought it was too obvious)?

Comment: @DanielWagner I was previously talking with AsadSaeeduddin at https://funprog.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/201385-Haskell/topic/Fixed.20size.20containers. I had trouble proving that `husk . unhusk == id`, but it looks like you’ve managed to prove that already.

Comment: Tangential musings: `unhusk :: f x -> x` poses questions like "given `data Duo x = Duo x x`, which `unhusk` should I pick?". Answering "both" already points towards `Distributive` territory: `distribute id :: Distributive g => g (g a -> a)`. The further step towards `Representable` and `Rep f = forall x. f x -> x` is rife with technical annoyances, [as I once found out in another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919305/2751851).